# Mass Email Acknowledgement Options

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, send-email, docusign

Business has a need to send out mass communications/emails to internal staff. With these emails, they would like a button or signature option to appear in these emails that the recipient would have to "sign" essentially stating that they acknowledge the email. Any suggestions on what tool to use to accomplish this? We have some apps currently such as DocuSign and Exact Target, but just looking for any opinions on what works best. Thanks as always.

Comment: Is the communication targeting a List or a Data Extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have ET landing pages and you're sending the email from ET you can have an "Accept" button or link in the email that will link to a landing page.  If you use the `MicrositeBaseUrl` AMPscript function for the link in the email you can grab the email of the person who clicks the link with some AMPscript on the landing page and add their name to a data extension or update a field in an existing data extension.  The code to grab the email address in the landing page would go at the top of the page and look something like this:

```
%%[ VAR @emailaddress
        SET @emailaddress = emailaddr
        /* Code to add or update DE goes here */
]%%
HTML of page goes here
```

If you're not using ET to send the email but you have access to ET landing pages you can put the email or other identifier in the query string of the link and pull it out using AMPscript.

The link would look something like this:

```
<a href="http://pathtoETlandingpage.com&email=youruseremail@email.com>Accept</a>
```

The AMPscript on the page would look something like this:

```
%%[ VAR @emailaddress
        SET @emailaddress = RequestParameter("email")
        /* Code to add or update DE goes here */
]%%
HTML of page goes here
```